# delete files having a certain pattern in their names

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, wildcards

I want to delete all files that have two numbers and a dot in **beginning** of their names
for example:

```
01. abc
02. xyz
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
rm [0-9][0-9].*
```

will do it for files in the current directory (no quotes — you *want* to match files). The `.` doesn't need to be escaped, because this is a shell glob and not a regular expression (if it were a regex, that would be a wildcard).

If you are looking to do this recursively, `find` is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 8):

Recursively :

```
find . -type f -name '[0-9][0-9].*' -delete
```

require GNU find, or :

```
find . -type f -name '[0-9][0-9].*' -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: If it's just files in the current dir, simply `rm '[0-9][0-9].*'`

Comment: @glennjackman Yes but no quotes in that case.

Comment: whats different between two

Comment: @edwardtorvalds, in quotes, it's a literal string. Without quotes, it will expand to match filenames.

Comment: @glennjackman I am talking about use of `rm` and `-delete`

Comment: @glennjackman if you are providing `-exec` option then whats the difference is there for `rm` and `-delete` because in this case it does not matters whether `rm` looks at current directory or not. `rm` gets full path

Comment: Ack. I didn't see sputnick changing his answer. Alright: `-exec rm {} \;` has to spawn an new process for `rm` for each file found. `-delete` is built-in to find, so it will be more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the files recursively with '-r' option

```
rm -rf name_pattern*    
eg : rm -rf dept*
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, since it's about matching file names beginning with *any* two digits followed by a period. The question didn't mention anything about files being in subdirectories either, so not sure why mention the recursive option.